# Verticals windows TabBar Menu and animated indicator in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, position, tabbar

I would like to know how I can make this kind of menu on flutter with the indicator that moves on each menu item and it is on the divider.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Seems it is using animatedPosition on stack

Comment: @YeasinSheikh And how do I track the indicator on the currently selected element? Note that it works like the TabBar widget indicator

Comment: You can use `LayoutBuilder` to separate screen, create views.  and show animation based on tap(selectedItem). also `IndexedStack` or `pageViewBuilder` may can be use as right part

Comment: I will try based on your answers and follow up, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried an approach that kind of works but is not responsive to device size, have a look at this
https://dartpad.dev/?id=6ef0d738ca732aab0f45c92d3390310f&null_safety=true

Comment: Wow, Thank you for your help, I will use your example to understand how it works and try to do it again, a huge thank you